# Is there a quick way of splitting concentric circles made with the polar grid tool equally?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, grids

I'm in the process of drawing a game board using Illustrator and Photoshop. Each tile on this board should be approx. 1.5cm x 1.5cm, and I have the basic layout done simply using the Polar Grid tool. I was wondering is there a way to quickly draw the rest of the tiles to the correct measurement? Obviously I can't do it within the Polar Grid tool itself, as segmenting it leads to uneven spacing.

EDIT: I've been asked to provide a photo, so here's one:

[image]

It's not the best lighting, but hopefully you can see what I'm aiming for.

Comment: Do you have any image that you can add to the question about what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think the polar grid is a particularly good way to create something like your example image.

I would use a pattern brush to do it, and here's how I'd proceed:

1. uncheck the option "Scale strokes and effects" located in Preferences under the General tab
2. create a pattern brush like the one shown below - it was made from a square, filled white, with black stroke, then I deleted the right edge
3. draw a circle, apply the pattern brush, set the stroke to 1 pt, no fill
4. copy and paste in place additional circles, and transform each circle by holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> as you click and drag a corner handle

Edit: I suppose you could also do a blend between two circles if you wanted to automate the placement of circles as shown in Danielillo's answer (which is probably better than mine).

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A quick way is adding a dashed white stroke to the circles. Change the dash distance to get as many partitions as you wish.

[image: white stroke]

And a second thicker black stroke with no dash added from the appearance panel:

[image: black stroke]

Saving the stroke as a Graphic Style, you can make a Blend between two circles:

[image: Blend]